# Print the string in C from the Java string obtained

Tags: java, c

I have this code in Java: where value is byte array

```
            String a = "";

            for (int index = 4; index < 8; index++) {

                if (a.isEmpty()) {
                    a+= (value[index] & 0xFF);
                } else {
                    a+= "." + (value[index] & 0xFF);
                }

            }

            return (a);
```

How can I convert it in C?

Comment: what this code actually doing?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did that work? How didn't it work? And can you please elaborate a little? Do you want to make a C version of the Java code?

Comment: I'm afraid its going to take *writing* some C code to make that conversion a reality.

Comment: It seems like it's just interspersing with dots.

Comment: Looks like code that converts an IPv4 address to a string on the form "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to just do it, skip the loop and the dotting logic since you know what you want:

```
char a[128];

sprintf(a, "%d.%d.%d.%d",
    value[4] & 0xFF, value[5] & 0xFF, value[6] & 0xFF, value[7] & 0xFF);
```

If you have it, use `snprintf()` to be safer.